# Rails: duplicating information into another model if conditions met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, nested-forms

I've got a list of articles with checkboxes on a form. When a box is checked, the body of the selected article is copied into one of `x` text areas.

Should a user want to make a change to the body of an article in the text area I need to send that change through my controller into a new Rails model (called an `Edit`).

I already have the record being created, I just need the application to record the changes into a new `Edit` record. Here's my relevant **controller** code:

**new**

```
def new
  @template = Template.find(params[:template])
  @article_count = @template.pages-1
  @doc = Doc.new
  @doc.template_id = @template.id
  @doc.user_id = current_user.id
  @articles = current_user.brand.articles
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @doc }
  end
end
```

**create**

```
def create
  @doc = Doc.new(params[:doc])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @doc.save
      #make editable version
      if current_user.brand.try(:editable?)
        @doc.articles.each do |article|
          @edit = Edit.new
          @edit.name = article.name
          @edit.video = article.video
          #something here to get the bodies of the text areas
          @edit.article_id = article.id
          @edit.doc_id = @doc.id
          @edit.user_id = current_user.id
          @edit.save
        end
      end
      @doc.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
      format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc.user.ftp, @doc) }
      format.json { render json: @doc, status: :created, location: @doc }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @doc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the code that makes the text areas in the **view**.

```
<% @article_count.times do |article| %>
  <div id="edit<%= article %>" class="tab-pane <%= "active" if article == 0 %>">
    <%= text_area_tag("edit[#{article}][body]") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Records are created for each article, but I can't seem to be able to save the edits from the text areas. It's kind of a nested-form arrangement. Any help at all would be definitely appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by breaking the form up into two pages: one handles the selection, the second the editing. Given that a `Doc` has many `edits`, this is the method I made for part two of the form:

```
def edit_content
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
  if !@doc.edits.exists?
    @doc.articles.reverse.each do |article|
      @doc.edits.build(:body => article.body)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps someone.